# export variables into Excel continious

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export

Hi guys im using this command to count Users inside a specific OU

```
$datum=get-date -Format MM-yyyy
$norm=(get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Normal,OU=Benutzer und Computer,DC=my,DC=domain" -filter *|where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
$spec=(get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Special,OU=Benutzer und Computer,DC=my,DC=Domain" -filter *|where {$_.enabled -e "True"}).count
```

I mail myself the results monthly with Send-MailMessage

Now i want to save the results in a continuous Excel / CSV file. I found some faqs but i cant figure out how to export it the right way.

I would like to add the numbers i get it in 3 different colums automatically.

/ Date / Special / Normal /

Whats the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
[PsCustomObject]@{Date=$datum;Normal=$norm;Special=$spec} | 
    Export-Csv .\Data.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I assumed that by 'continuous' you meant that you were going to write to the same CSV over and over, hence the `-Append`.  Remove that if you want each attempt to over-write any existing data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [PSCustomObject](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/) to achieve it like this -

```
$datum = get-date -Format MM-yyyy
$norm =(get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Normal,OU=Benutzer und Computer,DC=my,DC=domain" -filter *|where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
$spec =(get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Special,OU=Benutzer und Computer,DC=my,DC=Domain" -filter *|where {$_.enabled -e "True"}).count

$obj = New-Object PSObject  
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value $datum 
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ADUserNormal" -Value $norm
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ADUserSpecial" -Value $spec 
$obj | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\File.csv -NoTypeInformation
```